In which cases is the ASAN shadow memory checked on pointer dereference?
Consider this example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void __asan_poison_memory_region(void const volatile *addr, size_t size);
void __asan_unpoison_memory_region(void const volatile *addr, size_t size);

int main(void) {
    uint64_t a[10] = {0};
    __asan_poison_memory_region(a, 10*sizeof(uint64_t));
    uint64_t* b = a;
    __asan_poison_memory_region(b, 10*sizeof(uint64_t));
    a[1] = 4; // nothing
    b[1] = 4; // use-after-poision
    return 0;
}

Compile with:
clang -fsanitize=address asan.c -o asan.exe

You will notice that the address sanitizer only reports the b[1]=4 access and not the a[1]=2 access despite the memory being poisoned (actually twice).
So the ASAN looks at the shadow memory only in the b case, am I right?
Here is my question, when does it check whether memory has been poisoned and when not?
I want to experiment with ASAN a little and see what cool things are possible to do with it. But I realize that the simplified view I had of how ASAN works is wrong, I cannot mark arbitrary portions of memory as poisoned and have a guarantee that ASAN will report the illegal access, maybe you can enlighten me what is going on?
Expected behaviour: both accesses are reported (the first one actually because the program stops) and even withb[1]=4; uncommented ASAN still reports an error about a[1] = 4;.

GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/v34r4hY65

Oh, I tested now on wsl, it works there. But why does it not work on my windows machine?

I now tested with MSVC it does work there, maybe I should check my ASAN runtime with clang.exe. The funny thing is, that godbolt msvc also does not throw an ASAN error, but it does that even when both lines are uncommented.
